# Can I use two suffix in the same spring boot project?

Tags: jsp, spring-boot, primefaces, xhtml

I'm actually working on a spring boot project using jsp pages as suffix. And now I want to make charts using primefaces. I know that primefaces doesn't support jsp so, can I use two suffix (xhtml and jsp) in the same spring boot project ?? or I should move them to xhtml 
Any ideas ? help me please

Answer (score 0):

Insert this code to your  [@Configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Configuration.html) class"

```
@Bean
public ServletRegistrationBean servletRegistrationBean() {
    FacesServlet servlet = new FacesServlet();
    ServletRegistrationBean servletRegistrationBean =
            new ServletRegistrationBean(servlet, "*.xhtml", "*.jsf");
    return servletRegistrationBean;
}
```